# Optimizing php conditionals

Tags: php

I have something like this:

```
<?php

$fix1 = XXXXXXX //Integer. Problem isn't here. Extracted automatically

$iffix1 = range(9000000,8000000);
$iffix2 = range(7999999,7888888);
...

//There're more iffix[XX]s, up to $iffix60

if($fix1 = in_array($iffix1)) {
    $var1 = 1;
} elseif($fix2 = in_array($iffix2)){
    $var2 = 2;
} ....

//I have 60 more elseifs as well

$result = $var1 * $fix1;
echo $result;

?>
```

The script is more complicated than that, but the question question only concerns this bit, Obviously, I get a low-memory error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your syntax at `$fix1 = in_array($iffix1)` is invalid (or at least, it's not doing what you think it's doing)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Why have anybody voted down this? Is this not a perfectly valid question?

Comment: @AJweb being a perfectly _valid_ question doesn't make it a **good** question. It seems to me that the poster lacks the most basic programming skill and it would be more useful for him to read a tutorial on PHP than for us to answer his specific question.

Comment: @Core Xii, I understand the point, but disagree. Do you need to have a given level of skills to post a question without being downvoted? We all can see the user has just started on SO. It is not a very welcoming message to someone trying to learn as we all do. Anyway, I realize this is a comment better suited for a meta thread, so I better leave it.

Comment: Sorry about my expression im spanish and my english level is not to high, i tried to express well, respect of the tutorial php i readed a book about programming in php and i don't find the answer, i watch in php.net the function range and in_array and i think "oh, can be okey", but not. Sorry for the inconvenients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having any real clue what you're trying to do, here's some code:

```
$ranges = array(
    array(8000000,9000000),
    array(7888888,7999999),
    ...
);

$fix = 1234567;
$var = 0;

foreach($ranges as $range) {
    $var++;
    if($range[0] < $fix1 && $fix1 < $range[1])
        break;
}

echo $fix * $var
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if($fix1 == in_array($iffix1)){
```

you could do

```
if($fix1 >= 8000000 && $fix1 <= 9000000) {
```

That way, you could get rid of the `$iffix`-arrays, so you wouldn't have to store an array of ~1 million integers. In addition, it's much faster checking the two outer bounds, rather than checking each of the 1 million integers inside.

The same goes for the other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$iffix*` arrays are really big, containg thousands of items, it seems -- which requires a lot of memory, and can explain you go beyond `memory_limit`, which causes a Fatal Error.

The wisest idea would be to re-think what you are doing, to avoid needing so much memory.

Else, you'll probably have to increase the value of [**`memory_limit`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) -- but if this is for a webapplication with many users, it's probably not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Your whole design is questionable. Instead of having 60 variables, use an array of variables (Rule of thumb: If you have numbers in your variable name, you're doing it wrong). Instead of generating all the numbers in a range, use an object representing the range. And be aware that `if ($fix1 = in_array(...))` actually changes the value of `$fix1`.